# Ortografía de anglicismos técnicos

Tags: ortografía, anglicismo

Estoy con un texto de productos dentales que contiene muchas palabras técnicas, algunas traducidas y otras no. Por ejemplo "composite" no se suele traducir, aunque lo correcto sería hablar de "compuesto".

El problema es en palabras como "opaquer" y "opaquers" (opacador u obturador). En ocasiones es traducido cuando es adjetivo (líquido opacador), pero no cuando es sustantivo (el producto). No encontré ninguna página que aclare la versión correcta y la RAE no suele incluir términos técnicos.

*Opaquer*, en caso de ser adaptada al castellano, es una palabra grave, por lo que debe llevar acento: "opáquer". En la mayoría de los textos técnicos aparece sin acento, por lo que se entiende que no está traducida.

El problema aún mayor es el plural: opaquers, opáquers, opáqueres; las tres aparecen en prácticamente todos los textos técnicos.

¿Dónde o a quién hay que recurrir para solventar dichas dudas?

PD.: ¡Me navegué todo internet!

Comment: Eso del opáquer es francamente un poco ridículo. La palabra en inglés es un substantivo y la idea es opacificador. Hay que ir por el sentido. Nada más.

Comment: ¿Se lo cuentas tu uno por uno a todos los odontólogos, ortodoncistas, higienistas, clínicos dentales, distribuidores y mayoristas dentales, depósitos dentales, etc.?

Comment: Danielillo: tú no citas los sitios. PERO, opáquer es una traducción directa que no lleva en cuenta el significado en español. I have 40 years experience as a professional translator (law, technical, business, etc. etc.) and I know how to do the research regarding meanings and existing translations. An opaqu**er** is **a product that makes things on teeth opaque** (color, metal etc.) As such, it requires a noun for the meaning in Spanish. The best translation I found is the one in my answer: opacificad**or**. O sea un producto que hace *opaco* algo como manchas, metal etc. en los dientes. :)

Comment: Incorpora un opacificador de color blanco para el maquillaje del metal expuesto. https://dentpro.es/cemento-definitivo/4922-panavia-f-20-kit-completo-white-blanco-opaco.html Es otro exemplo de una buena traducción del sentido.

Comment: Ya, el tema pasa porque yo no intento ni tampoco puedo re-educar al Colegio de Odontólogos de España y Latinoamérica. Si en un texto el profesional lee _opacificador_ genera más incertidumbre que _opáquer_ mal escrito. Por eso intento encontrar una "adaptación" o regla que me permita unificar este término como otros tantos que aparecen en estos textos (es un manual de 250 páginas). _Composite_ está adaptado, quizás por el tema de los acentos que no tiene, aunque la mayoría (no sé si todos) lo pronuncian españolizándolo. _Opáquer_ es diferente. Igualmente preguntaré lo de _opacificador_.

Comment: composite es otro término.  Enmascaramiento: **Proceso de aplicar un opacificador que cubra y camufle el metal de una prótesis**. https://www.seguros-dentales.es/e.html

Comment: Tema 37: **Tintes y opacificadores en odontología estética**. Concepto. Física óptica de la ocultación de las coloraciones anormales. “Creación” de dientes naturales. https://guias.usal.es/node/108665 Universidad de Salamanca. [Hay mucha mala traducción en internet. opacificador está correcto.] Creo que ya es suficiente. Repito: opaquer in English is noun that means make something opaque.

Answer (score 1):

¡Espero que pueda ayudarte en algo con algunas de estas ideas relacionadas!

En español el sustantivo de "opaco" es "opacidad".

[image]

Por otro lado tienes el verbo **opacificar**  referenciado a "Hacer algo opaco" y el verbo **opacar**, con el mismo significado.

- https://dle.rae.es/opacar?m=form (conjugación de opacar)
- https://dle.rae.es/opacificar?m=form (conjugación de opacificar)

Así mismo como sinónimo de "opacador" se encuentra el término **opacante** (opacar). Término común que se utiliza para referirse a un tipo de polvo de color blanco utilizado para bajar el brillo de esmaltes sintéticos.

Otro término que creo que puedes utilizar, ya que suena también de forma muy natural, es el **opacificantes** (verbo opacificar), que igualmente esta referida a una sustancia que se añade al esmalte para que sea más opaco.

No se si alguno de estos términos podrían encajar en los plurales que utilizas (opacantes (opacar), opacificantes (opacificar)). Ejem. "*En este sentido los opacificantes utilizados son altamente eficaces...*"

La aplicación del "Opacador Composite..." donde el término "**Composite**" ya se encuentra castellanizado.

[image]

Comment: Me gusta _opacante_ pero si lo uso se me viene el Colegio de Odontólogos encima. Lo preguntaré.

Comment: Opacante/opacantes, es un término que se utiliza desde antiguo. https://www.google.es/books/edition/Manual_de_histolog%C3%ADa_normal/vUkLAQAAIAAJ?hl=es&gbpv=1&bsq=opacante&dq=opacante&printsec=frontcover

Comment: opaquer es un substantivo.

Comment: Si, Lambie, es cierto y además es frecuentemente utilizado en el ámbito dental, aunque la RAE no lo recoja como tal.

Comment: El término es opacificador. El er es algo que hace opaco. En español: or. Tabulator, tabulador.

Comment: A veces las preguntas y respuestas sufren de ma fe por esto lares. Soy la única traductora profesional aqui y puse toda la explicacion lingüístico y incluso usos por universitários en el campo de dentistas. No trabajo hacia el español (escrito) pero sei hacer investigación en terminologia ...Pero alto nivel aqui no parece interesar el que hizo la pregunta. Vuelvo a repetir: An opaque**r** is a product that makes something opaque. Therefore, it cannot be opacante, nor is it resina compuesta. It's like a dye to put over stains on teeth and to cover metal.

Comment: Lambie, estoy de acuerdo contigo.

Answer (score 0):

opaquer= opacificador:

Descripción

> Pink Opaquer, es un excelente producto capaz de BLOQUEAR esos
> insedeseables colores oscuros que se transparentan a través de las
> restauraciones afectando la estética final.
>
> Este producto se diferencia de otros **opacificadores**, porque tiene la
> capacidad de NEUTRALIZAR los colores muy oscuros, y a la vez,
> incrementar el valor con calidez, permitiendo al dentista conseguir
> resultados estéticos Excelentes.Descripción Pink Opaquer, es un
> excelente producto capaz de BLOQUEAR esos insedeseables colores
> oscuros que se transparentan a través de las restauraciones afectando
> la estética final.
>
> Este producto se diferencia de otros **opacificadores**, porque tiene la
> capacidad de NEUTRALIZAR los colores muy oscuros, y a la vez,
> incrementar el valor con calidez, permitiendo al dentista conseguir
> resultados estéticos Excelentes.

[Buena traducción](https://www.euromas.es/euromaswp/producto/pink-opaquer/)

Es la mejor traducción que encontré.

El **or** en español es el **er** en inglés en este caso.

Otro site:

POR: Adela Hervás García, Miguel Angel Martínez Lozano, Jose Cabanes Vila,
Amaya Barjau Escribano, Pablo Fos Galve

(1) **Profesores de Patología y Terapéutica Dental. Departamento de Atención Sanitaria Salud Pública y Sanidad Animal.
Universidad Cardenal Herrera-CEU. Moncada. Valencia**

**Una cosa distinta son los opacificadores [opaquers], materiales resinosos que se usan para tapar el color dental subyacente**. El uso de estos últimos materiales quita la transparencia del diente, lo cual obliga a suplirla artificialmente, con la combinación de materiales, en este caso un composite híbrido que recubre al opacificador etc.

[opacificador, el término usado por profesionales españoles de Patología y Terapéutica Dental](https://scielo.isciii.es/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1698-69462006000200023)